# I was overpaid by my company in California. Should I return the money?

Tags: california, employer, salary

Part of my signed agreement with my employer was that I will receive an extra sum of money for 5 months, but I've been receiving that for a year. Then the HR emailed me saying it's been overlooked by them and that I need to repay the money. My impression was that the extra sum was coming from another salary increase in the new year but it seems like they're right and it's been the original extra payment.
Am I required to return the money in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The general common law rule is that you are only entitled to money that you earn through a contract or are given as a gift: a mistaken overpayment is neither.

Your employer is not entitled to take it from your pay unless you agree and they must accept a reasonable repayment plan. If you can’t agree, they can sue you and get a court order to garnishee your wages.